# Error NSMutableURLRequest swift

Tags: swift, swift2, swift3

Tengo este código:

```
let urlString = "https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/snapToRoads?path="
let url = URL(string: urlString)
print(url)// Escribe=> nil
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url:url)//Aqui da error
```

el error que da es: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

El problema creo que es la longitud de la url. que paso muchos parametros

Answer (score 0):

el problema es que estas usando un valor opcional, y los valores opcionales pueden llegar a regresar un nulo, para evitar esto puedes hacer lo siguiente

```
let urlString = "https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/snapToRoads?path="
        let url = URL(string: urlString)
        print(url!)// Escribe=> nil
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url:url!)//Aqui forzas que no exista nulo
```

Print: https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/snapToRoads?path=